# Loading HOC with Thunk problem with props propagation

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I created an HOC to deal with loading. It uses a property `isLoading` to decide what to show.

When I open a page directly from the URL I haven't any issue and everything works fine (because `isLoading` property is setted up on `true` by default).
The problem is that when I click on a link (`<Link ... />`) things doesn't work as expected because `isLoading` is now `false` because the page where I am navigating from setted the state to this value.

So, this is the HOC:

```
import React from 'react';
export default function WithLoading(WrappedComponent, loadingDelegate) {
    class LoadingComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {

            super(props);
            this.state = {
                isLoading: true
            };
            this.loadingDelegate = loadingDelegate;
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            loadingDelegate(this);
        }

        render() {
            if (this.props.isLoading === true) {
                return (
                    <div>Loading...</div>
                );
            } else {
                return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
            }
        }
    }

    return LoadingComponent;
}
```

And below the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { actionCreators } from './SurveysStore';
import WithLoading from '../LoadingHOC';
//edit/:id
class SurveyDetailRoutedComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.survey.questions.length}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const SurveyDetailRoutedComponentWithLoading = WithLoading(SurveyDetailRoutedComponent, (_context) => _context.props.requestSurvey(parseInt(_context.props.match.params.id)));
export default connect(
    state => state.surveysReducer,
    dispatch => bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
)(SurveyDetailRoutedComponentWithLoading);
```

The error I have is that `survey` is null, because I tried to render a not already resolver property.

**The problem occurs only when I render this component via a `<Link>` contained in a page rendered in the same way**.

I tried to set `isLoading=true` on the routing, but this doesn't work for me:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Route exact path='/' component={(props) => <Home {...props} />} />
                <Route path='/survey/edit/:id' component={(props) => <SurveyDetailRoutedComponent {...props} isLoading={true} />} />
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

The store itself is very simple and I imagine my error is on how I deal with redux, because it looks like the routing operation is not resetting the loading.

```
const resetLoading = "RESET_LOADING";
const requestSurveys = "REQUEST_SURVEYS";
const receiveSurveys = "RECEIVE_SURVEYS";
const requestSurvey = "REQUEST_SURVEY";
const receiveSurvey = "RECEIVE_SURVEY";
const initialState = { surveys: [], isLoading: true, survey: null };
export const actionCreators = {
    resetLoading: () => function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({ type: resetLoading })
    },
    requestSurveys: () => async function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({ type: requestSurveys });
        const response = await fetch(...)
        const responseAsJson = await response.json();
        dispatch({ type: receiveSurveys, surveys: responseAsJson.data.surveys });
    },
    requestSurvey: id => async function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({ type: requestSurvey });

        const response = await fetch(...)
        const responseAsJson = await response.json();
        dispatch({ type: receiveSurvey, survey: responseAsJson.data.survey });
    }
};

export const reducer = function(state, action) {
    state = state || initialState;
    switch (action.type) {
        case resetLoading:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case requestSurveys:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case requestSurvey:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case receiveSurveys:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                surveys: action.surveys
            };
        case receiveSurvey:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                survey: action.survey
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```